# Converting a string of UTF code point to its respective value

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the following string \u5733. I need to convert this to its respective UTF value. I tried doing it in both the ways shown below but I end up with "?" as the output. The UTF code points is for a Chinese character.Any help would be appreciated.

```
char[] arr=Character.toChars(5733);
System.out.println(new String(arr));

String code = "5733";
char c = (char)Integer.parseInt(code, 16);
System.out.println("Code: " + code + " Character: " + c);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a problem with the terminal where your output is shown since your second approach is working for me.

Your first approach contains an error though. Since 5733 is a hexadecimal number, you should prefix it with `0x`:

```
char[] arr=Character.toChars(0x5733);
```

An even simpler method would be:

```
char c = 0x5733;
System.out.println("Code: " + (int)c + " Character: " + c);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this in Eclipse, you can display UTF-8 characters as follows:

- Click Run Configurations...
- Select your particular Run Config for this App
- Click Common->Encoding->Other
- Select UTF-8
- Run